# iOS Swift App - Database

Tags: ios, swift, app-config

I'm learning Swift & am able to construct a basic app. I have an app in mind as the end goal that will allow users to log in, answer questions (which are constantly being added to by me & record their results.

This is obviously going to require a database of some form hosted & accessible online. My thoughts are that this would be done using something like a MySQL Db (like website databases), but is this the best & generally accepted way of doing things?

Comment: yes your thoughts are correct,,also do some research.and post question with code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to host it somewhere on the web, I think that the best solution would be to create REST API ( you can write that in any language, I will name few: Rails, C#, Java, PHP, Python ). I think that in general it is a bad practice to have direct calls to remote database within your swift app.

If you want local database for users you could use SQLite, Core Data, Realm and other similar tools.

To have everything covered you could create some kind of database as a service and use that one instead of REST API. That would be Parse, Firebase etc. These services are free for start, but expensive as you expand your requirements.

Comment: Thank you both for your guidance on this. Some bed time reading due! Interesting comment re-accessing remote database not being wise.  Presumably for security reasons?  Out of interest, what sort of Dbs would the likes of Facebook & Twitter be using?

Comment: Well, Fb&Twitter use the same database for the website, they have only API for calls. What exact database is in use I am not sure, but if you have user base for millions of user, database is minor problem :P
Here is an programmers.stackoverflow question regarding using API so you can read that as well : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170463/why-to-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-access-to-a-relational-database-for-an

Comment: Hmmm. That's interesting. So basically you have some form of Ali middle man going to something like a MySQL Db (or several). This would work well to make the app android or browser compatible at a later date.

Comment: Yeah... BUT! If you don't want to mess with backend code, you can use Database as a service like Parse or Firebase. Firebase is reusable on web as well. Just note that if your application expand pretty big you will have to pay a lot of money. But, since your app is viral, that's not what concerns you most :)

Comment: I guess everyone wants a viral app! It's more about building something that's fit for purpose. I think I'm getting ahead of myself & don't fully understand everything just yet.

Comment: Well at least you started with something :) you have to communicate with database in order to have dynamic app - otherwise you will have to update app each time you have new content - e.g. new posts, stories etc. I don't know what is your app, but there are few apps that don't need database, and almost all of them are utilities like alarm and stuff like that. If you have any kind of user you should have online database ( and perhaps web-site, but that's optional)

Comment: Hope you got something in your mind for your solution as well as learned something :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, it's starting to make sense now. The end app is a quiz app that will have evolving content. The database - whatever it is therefore needs to be online. I fully get this now & could be MySQL or something else.  Then I need an API running on a webserver to direct the traffic to the right place, so that I can tweak things without breaking old apps.  Alternatively parse & firebase are both api & Db right?

Comment: yup, thats right :) API for parse and firebase are provided within the framework - if you need something custom, for Parse you can write it in javascript(not sure for Firebase)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. I feel I understand the principles on this now. I feel there's a lot to learn though! I'm a good designer & although I understand html & css, I usually pay someone else to do the coding work. Wondering whether this should be the case here...

Comment: And please accept the answer if you find it helpfull :)

Comment: Just click at the checkmark next to the answer, you will get reputation as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides [Core Data framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1) to work with databases on iOS.

There are other options too, but I prefer [Realm](http://realm.io). It' very easy to learn and use. [Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81615/introduction-to-realm) a tutorial for it.

Comment: Realm looks nice! I presume core data is no good if you want to build an android equivalent app to run off same Db content?

Comment: These are ok for simple apps. I want one that allows users to interact & get new content, so Nicks solution is the way forward for me. Thanks for the advice though. Was useful in allowing me to rationalise my understanding.